# Не могу настроить авторизацию HttpBearerAuth в Yii2

Tags: yii2, rest, auth

Делаю REST API. Есть контроллер, который хранить в себе общие правила. От него наследуется контроллер, который позволяет обращаться только авторизированым

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className()
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

Есть конфиг роутеров

```
[
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'pluralize' => false,
                    'controller' => ['v1/patient' => 'v1/patient'],
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        '/' => 'index',
                        'create' => 'create',
                        'search' => 'search',
                        'remove' => 'remove',
                        'one' => 'one'
                    ]
                ]
```

Проблема в том, что когда идет первый запрос OPTIONS, он получает 403, потому что при OPTIONS не передается токен.

Как сделать, что бы OPTIONS пропускало без токена или как сделать передачу токена в OPTIONS? И если я что то вообще не то делаю, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Перед отправкой ответа надо проверить, является ли запрос OPTIONS, если да, то обработать ответ дополнительно. У меня сделано костыльно для все контроллеров и экшенов, потому что они практически все поддерживают эти типы запросов, но по-хорошему можно создать компонент, который будет "выяснять" поддерживаемые методы экшена.

```
 'components' => [
    'response' => [
        'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
            $event->sender->headers->add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            $event->sender->headers->add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS');
            $event->sender->headers->add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, tz');
            if (Yii::$app->request->isOptions) {
                $event->sender->statusCode = 200;
                $event->sender->data = null;
            }
        },
```